# Can we apply the component test for the given field?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

> Consider the following vector field $\mathbf F$, where
> $$\mathbf F=x^3\sin\left(\frac1x\right)\mathbf{i}+(2x+e^y)\mathbf{j}+\left(\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right)\mathbf{k}$$
> defined on its domain. Can you apply the Component Test for Conservative Fields to check whether the vector field is conservative or not. If yes, then use it to check whether $\mathbf F$ is conservative or not. If not, explain.

I understand that to apply the component test for any field, the domain must be simply connected. But for such a field, how can we determine whether the domain is simply connected or not?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and also show the work you have done so far.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).. I have tried to improve your post using TeX (for better readability). Please check whether these edits did not unintentionally change the meaning of your post.

Comment: Is the domain $\mathbb{R}^2$ here? I am asking because the question you have mentioned does not clarify

Comment: Yes I think the domain is R^2 here

Comment: $\mathbb R^2$ does not make sense, since the notion of a conservative field only makes sense if domain and image have the same dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you should say what the domain actually is. I assume it's all the purely imaginary quaternions $x \,\boldsymbol i + y \,\boldsymbol j+ z \,\boldsymbol k$ for which the formula is defined. That would be $Im\mathbb H$ minus the plane spanned by $\boldsymbol j$ and $\boldsymbol k$, which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^3$ minus the $(y,z)$-plane, which is homotopy equivalent to the $x$-axis minus the origin by projecting, which has two simply connected components. That should be enough for your component test.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the notation. Here $\mathbf i$, $\mathbf j$ and $\mathbf k$ are probably supposed to mean the three-dimensional unit vectors.

Comment: Well, the imaginary quaternions are a 3d real vector space with basis $\boldsymbol i$, $\boldsymbol j$, and $\boldsymbol k$. So we're essentially talking about the same thing.

Comment: I agree on that. Just meant that quaternions is probably not the notion which the OP had in mind with his question.

Comment: Possibly, although I've never seen those symbols used for the standard basis of $\mathbb R^3$. Anyway, that's for the OP to clarify.

Comment: It is a quite common notation in physics.

Answer (score 0):

The maximal domain of the given vector field is $ D= \mathbb R^3\setminus \{(x,y,z):x=0\}$. This is not simply connected, since a closed curve around the $x$-axis can not be contracted to a point. However, if you restrict the domain to a simply connected set, e.g., the half space $D_+ = \{(x,y,z):x>0\} $, then you can apply the component test.

Comment: Careful, your domain $D$ is the disjoint union of two open half spaces, both of which are contractible. In particular, all loops in $D$ can be contracted to points.